# SQLite and range query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How could I perform a simple range query in SQLite efficiently?

Say, I have data that saves a person information and I want to find the people with age between 20~45, and weight between 50~80kg?

What should I do (like setting certain index?) to make the searching more efficient?

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like

```
SELECT PersonName FROM Persons WHERE (Age BETWEEN 20 AND 45) AND (Weight BETWEEN 50 AND 80)
```

---

Indexing the fields Age and Weight would help speeding up the query.

Here's a nice overview about indexing in SQLite: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm

Answer (score 7):

SQLite's [documentation for the R-tree module](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) says:

> An R-Tree is a special index that is designed for doing range queries.