# Optimize SQLite Range Query

Tags: sqlite

I use an `SQLite` DB in my python application. I have to do many queries of the form

```
SELECT * from positions where (x between ? and ? ) and (y between ? and ?)
```

I already created an index with the following structure:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS positions_idx ON positions (x, y)
```

Is there any way to improve the query speed? Especially, is a single combined index better than two separate indices?

**Edit**

A similar question was already [asked on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331597/sqlite-and-range-query). The solution presented there makes use of an R*Tree.  I dont quite understand how to construct such an R*Tree in SQL. The line

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE r_tree_pos USING rtree(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax);
```

would just create an empty table which I would have to populate. Do I have to create manually an R*Tree from my original `positions` table and insert the result into the `r_tree_pos` table? A simple example  - maybe in `python` - would be great.